# Почему $result == 0 sql SELECT COUNT(*)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Я отправляю запрос

```
$mysql->query("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM `Users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password'");
```

и присваиваю это `$result`.

Почему `$result == 0`, хотя если `$password` и `$login` совпадают с `password` и `login` в базе данных *mysql*?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что $result это объект а не число